# Match all text before a number in string and after a number in string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Input text:

```
Mazzei, Toscana, sangiovese, merlot 2400
Papale, Puglia, primitive 2600
Antinori, Toscana, sangiovese, cabernet, sauvignon, merlot, syrah 2950
```

Desired output (without whitespace at the end):

```
Mazzei, Toscana, sangiovese, merlot
Papale, Puglia, primitive
Antinori, Toscana, sangiovese, cabernet, sauvignon, merlot, syrah
```

I also can't figure out:

Input text:

```
Mazzei 2400 Toscana, sangiovese, merlot
Papale 2600 Puglia, primitive
Antinori Toscana, sangiovese 2950 cabernet, sauvignon, merlot, syrah
```

Desired output (without whitespace at the end):

```
Toscana, sangiovese, merlot
Puglia, primitive
cabernet, sauvignon, merlot, syrah
```

Thank you.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using javascript I think is your question

Comment: Can you provide the code you've tried and the error you're receiving?

Comment: Uhh no I don't really have any code or a error I'm just copy pasting a lot of text and i'm tring to use regex to select it

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need two regexes to solve this:
Your first problem can be solved by this regex:

```
.+(?= \d+)
```

It matches one or more of any character which is followed by a Space and one or more digits.

Your second problem can be solved by this regex:

```
(?<=\d+ ).+
```

It matches one or more of any character which has digits and a space in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the digits from the string with `replace` and regexp, and maybe you want to clean up the text like remove extra spaces etc...

```js
console.log(
  "Antinori Toscana, sangiovese 2950 cabernet, sauvignon, merlot, syrah"
    .replace(/\d*/g, "") // remove numbers
    .replace(/\s+/g, " ") // convert double space to single one
    .trim() // remove space around the string
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function.

```js
const input = `Mazzei 2400 Toscana, sangiovese, merlot
Papale 2600 Puglia, primitive
Antinori Toscana, sangiovese 2950 cabernet, sauvignon, merlot, syrah`;

input.split(/\n/).forEach((line) => {
 const result = line.split(/[0-9]+/);
    console.log('Result:', result[1]);
});
```